# How to recall select after timeout in C?

Tags: c

I used **select** for synchronous I/O multiplexing.It will check for any data for 1 second.After 1 second if no data it will display a output (`puts("Waited for 1 sec no data");`) then it will check again for data.But this is working only at first time then it enters endless loops.
Is there any alternative solution for this.

```
//..............................
//.............................
//Creating listener socket and other sort of things
struct timeval tv;
        tv.tv_sec=1;
        tv.tv_usec=0;

    while(1)
    {
    FD_ZERO(master);


    FD_SET(listener,master);
    fdmax = listener;
    int retval=select(fdmax+1,master, NULL, NULL,&tv);
    printf("retval is %d\n",retval);

            if(retval == -1)
            {
                    perror("Server-select() error");
            }else if(retval)
            {
                    puts("Data available");
                    //If there is no data do some work and checkagain.

            }else
            {
                    puts("Waited for 1 sec no data"); 
                    //If there is no data do some work and checkagain.

            }
      }
```

Comment: the `timeval` structure declares timeouts. If you want to _wait_ one second between I/O, you should do as @Pierre recommends.

Comment: Does select() closes the socket after timeout?

Comment: Read the man page for `select` very thoroughly. It has a lot of hints: *Consider timeout to be undefined after select() returns.*

Comment: just put tv initalization after the "checkagain:" mark, and please do not use goto again

Comment: @tofro thanks I found that in man page.I will change the code and check again

Comment: also will remove goto

Comment: @tofro Thank you very much It's working now.

Comment: Use [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) instead of `select`

Comment: @Pierre what would be the purpose of using `sleep`? This code already does the right thing, other than the bug corrected by the accepted answer. `sleep` just adds useless time in which the app is neither doing work *nor* able to respond to I/O.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [man select](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select):

> On Linux, select() modifies timeout to reflect the amount of time not slept; most other implementations do not do this. (POSIX.1-2001 permits either behavior.) This causes problems both when Linux code which reads timeout is ported to other operating systems, and when code is ported to Linux that reuses a struct timeval for multiple select()s in a loop without reinitializing it. Consider timeout to be undefined after select() returns.

So like `master`, you will have to set `tv` before each `select` call.

In my codes, I often have something like:

```
FD_ZERO(master);
FD_SET(listener,master);
fdmax = listener;

while (1)
{
    struct timeval tv = {1, 0};

    int retval=select(fdmax+1,master, NULL, NULL,&tv);
    printf("retval is %d\n",retval);

    if(retval == -1) {
        perror("Server-select() error");
        break; //  <-- notice the break here
    } else if(retval) {
        puts("Data available");
    } else {
        puts("Waited for 1 sec no data"); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Mathieu answer, it seems that before each call to select FD_ZERO must be called to empty readable file handle set and then calls the FD_SET.

I was struggling with select() returning always 0 after reaching the timeout regardless the fact that there are data to read (I read inputs from the keyboard, I checked with 'cat' command that data are sent at each Key press).

The code should be (Credit to previous answers):

```
while (1)
{

    struct timeval tv = {1, 0};
    FD_ZERO(master);
    FD_SET(listener,master);
    fdmax = listener;

    int retval=select(fdmax+1,master, NULL, NULL,&tv);
    printf("retval is %d\n",retval);

    if(retval == -1) {
        perror("Server-select() error");
        break; //  <-- notice the break here
    } else if(retval) {
        puts("Data available");
    } else {
        puts("Waited for 1 sec no data"); 
    }
}
```