# break condition while reading from socket

Tags: sockets

I want to read a datastream from a socket and stop reading when the server has finished sending. The code below never runs the else if (because read never reads 0 bytes obviously ;) ). How can i break or modify the while loop for breaking after getting what i want from the server?

```
    while(1){
        /* receive answer from server */
        t = read(sock, output, MAX);
        if (t > 0) {
            puts("received smthn");
        }
        else if (t == 0) {
            puts("***ITS OVER***");
        } else {
            printf("Connection with server terminated.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Finished sending what? NB `read()` returns zero when the peer closes the connection.

Comment: the server is sending a string over a socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `read` function to return `0`, the server must close the socket on its side (see [`close`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/close)).

If the server forgot to call `close` on the socket, you could try to see if some data are ready to be read on the socket before reading: see [`select`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) or see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36786740/1212012